# Not subscribing cmd_vel/geometry_msgs/Twist

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi, I am using ros_enabled_model plugin with ros groovy . With the help of ros I am publishing `cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist`. I am able to publish the `cmd_vel` but on gazebo side subscriber is not working . Can anybody plz explain why it is not subscribing. Here is my code

```
public: void Load(physics::ModelPtr _parent, sdf::ElementPtr /*_sdf*/)                
{    
 node=new ros::NodeHandle("~");
 ros::SubscribeOptions so=ros::SubscribeOptions::create<geometry_msgs::Twist>("/cmd_vel", 1,boost::bind(&ModelPush::ROSCallback_Vel, this, _1),ros::VoidPtr(),node->getCallbackQueue());
              
 cmd_vel_sub=node->subscribe(so);

}



void ROSCallback_Vel(const geometry_msgs::Twist::ConstPtr &msg)
{
         
 ROS_INFO("I heard");
          
 ROS_INFO("I received odom: [%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf, %lf]",msg->linear.x,msg->linear.y,msg->linear.z,msg->angular.x,msg->angular.y,msg->angular.z);
    
 double velocity=msg->linear.x;
 
 double angularVelocity=msg->angular.z;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7667/not-subscribing-cmd_vel/geometry_msgs/twist/) by [anonymous](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/957/anonymous/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-12-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

you might need to call

```
ros::spinOnce();
```

in the update loop. Or use and asynchronous spinner. [Here](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning) are some spinning tutorials.

Cheers,
Andrei

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2014-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anonymous](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/957/anonymous/) on 2014-12-12**:
Ya its working now. Thanks!.

**Comment by [JuliusS](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2696/juliuss/) on 2016-07-08**:
When you say update loop, you mean the 'on update' function that is attached to ConnectWorldUpdateBegin?